# Slowly changing dimension

Tags: ssis

What is the use of Slowly changing dimension Task in SSIS 2008 ? How do we use it ?

What is the advantage of using this task ? Any performance difference from using Lookup and Conditional Split task ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of an open-ended question!  Have a look at these links...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141715.aspx

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/06/06/ssis_3a00_-scd-wizard-demo.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/11/13/handling-slowly-changing-dimensions-in-ssis.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Although there's lots of in depth information on the web about what a Slowly Changing Dimension is, here's a very common and simple use of it:

Let's say that you are trying to keep the contents of one table up to date with another table's contents.  For example, if you have one database (database A) that contains an item master (eg. an ERP system), and you want to have another database (database B) have the same item master data.  A slowly changing dimension will allow you to propogate changes from the item master Database A into Database B automatically.  For example, if a an item's field changes in db A, then that change will get propogated to db B; if a new item is inserted into db A, then that same item will get inserted into db B.
(Note that, in this scenario, deletions don't get propagated, since there's no record to trigger the deletion.)